# How Lp spaces relate regarding convergence

Tags: functional-analysis, convergence-divergence, lp-spaces, weak-convergence

I know that for a bounded $\Gamma$ it follows that $L^{q}(\Gamma) \subset L^{p}(\Gamma)$ if $q > p$.
I have a few questions regarding how $L^{p}$ spaces relate with regard to convergence. Consider $L^{p}$ spaces $L^{p}(\Gamma)$ and $L^{p-\epsilon}(\Gamma)$ where $\Gamma$ is a bounded subset of $\mathbb{R}$ and $\epsilon \in (0,p-1]$. If $u_{n} \rightarrow u$ in $L^{p-\epsilon}(\Gamma)$ can it be shown that $u_{n} \rightharpoonup u$ weakly in $L^{p}(\Gamma)$?

Secondly, if we consider the same spaces as above, how could we show that if $u_{n} \rightharpoonup u$ in $L^{p}(\Gamma)$ then $u_{n} \rightharpoonup u$ in $L^{p-\epsilon}(\Gamma)$?

Thanks!

Comment: I think you can deduce the answers from the following characterization of weak convergence in $L_p$: Let $\Sigma$ be a family of sets of finite measure whose characteristic functions form a fundamental set in $L_P(\Gamma)$. Then $(f_n)$ converges to $f$ weakly if and only if it is bounded in norm and $\lim_n \int_E f_n=\int_E f$ for all $E\in \Sigma$. (c.f. Exercise IV.13.24, Dunford and Schwartz, *Linear Operators, Part I. General Theory*.)

Answer (score 2):

The answer to the first question is no. Let $\Gamma=[0,1]$ and $u_n(x)=x^{-1/p}\chi_{[n^{-2},n^{-1}](x)}$. Then for any $q\in(1,p)$
$$
\int_\Gamma|u_n(x)|^q\,dx=\int_{n^{-2}}^{n^{-1}}x^{-q/p}\,dx\le\frac{n^{1-q/p}}{1-q/p}\to0\text{ as }n\to\infty.
$$
On the other hand
$$
\int_\Gamma|u_n(x)|^p\,dx=\int_{n^{-2}}^{n^{-1}}x^{-1}\,dx=\log n\to\infty\text{ as }n\to\infty.
$$
It follows that $u_n\to0$ in $L^q$ but $u_n\not\rightharpoonup0$ in $L^p$. Observe that $u_n$ and $u$ are in $L^p$.

The answer to the second question is yes, since $L^{q'}\subset L^{p'}$, that is, the dual of $L^q$ is contained in the dual of $L^p$. (As before $q\in(1,p)$.)

Comment: Hi Julien, how would you go about proving the result $L^{q^{'}} \subset L^{p^{'}}$ that you stated for the second answer?

Comment: If $1<q<p$ then $1<p'<q'$. Since $\Gamma$ is bounded...

Comment: I was referring to the whole reply for question two, I didn't ask the question properly. So is the reasoning simply that $(L^{q})^{*} \subset (L^{p})^{*}$ so $L^{p}$ has a finer weak topology than $L^{q}$ therefore if $u_{n} \rightharpoonup u$ in $L^{p}$ then $u_{n} \rightharpoonup u$ in $L^{q}$.